# Visual Studio npm scoped modules development?

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-2015

I have very little experience with nodejs/typescript/visual studio development, and could use some advice and directions.

I'm starting a new vs2015 solution to develop several nodejs scoped modules.
My questions are:

1. How should I structure my project folders?
2. Is there a particular toolchain or workflow I should use?

Here's what I've hacked together so far:
[image: VS2015 structure]

The project seems to compile and run fine, but there were quite a few issues:

- When something changes in @product/core, @product/analysis did not pick it up

  - Typescript error: Member not found
  - npm install/update does not work
- Have to manually delete node_modules followed by "npm install"

  - Deleting/reinstalling node_modules gets past typescript compiler errors
  - But then Resharper has problem picking it up, unless I unload/reload the project
    [image: Typescript/resharper errors]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Have to manually delete node_modules followed by "npm install"

This is the way to go. I feel like these IDEs should support `sync` like atom-typescript does : https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript#sync and so does alm : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/alm/content/features/typescript.html#sync

Sadly the sync version of VS is a restart / a big enough fs change at the moment.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I guess I can probably write a gulp task to automate deleting the node_modules folder and reinstall. Any thoughts on structuring the project directories? and also, using "file:...." to reference a local module? Thanks

Comment: `Any thoughts on structuring the project directories?` Start with everything in the root folder and then see how your project forces you to move stuff into folders naturally